# How do I check elements of the list here

Tags: python, list, append, permutation

I'm kinda new to Python.
as part of my code,I needed a function that checks the elements of a list and ignore it if difference between each element and the one after/before it is exactly 1.for example:

[1,2,5,10] is invalid

[9,14,19,18] is invalid

[3,6,9,20] is valid

Here's my code:

```
def code(self):

            for line,lists in enumerate(permutations(range(4))):
                valid_list = []
                for index,elements in enumerate(lists) :
                    if index != len(lists)-1:  #list index out of range escape condition
                        if lists[index] - lists[index+1] == 1 or lists[index+1] - lists[index] == 1 :
                            break


                    valid_list.append(lists)


            return good_items
```

so I want to check the elements of "permutation lists" and if they are Ok, append that list to the "valid_list" for final return but I'm struggling to do so.I dunno where should I put the valid_list.append(lists) so that when I made sure all the 3 elements(last one is not needed) are checked,it appends.

I would appreciate some help :3

P.s: so here's the thing,I know the algorithm is terrible and the actual code is as bad,I just wanna know how to make it work.
suggestions for improving the code are widely appreciated but not exactly what I'm looking for right now :3

Comment: What is your question? How to check the condition you are decribing, how to append to a list or how to fix the function with the descriptive name `code`?

Comment: @timgeb
I can't get the expected results.there are 24 lists generated from that permutations function.2 of them met my conditions which are:
[1,3,0,2] and [2,0,3,1]
but when I'm running this code ,I get an empty list, or [3,2,1,0] (last list when iteration is finished) which both obviously are not the answers.
I wanna know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `valid_list` should be out of the `for` loop, otherwise it will be overwritten. Besides, use a `flag_valid` to indicate whether the invalid elements exist. Try this code:

```
from itertools import permutations 

def code():
    valid_list = []
    for line,lists in enumerate(permutations(range(4))):        
        flag_valid = True
        for index,elements in enumerate(lists):
            if index != len(lists) - 1:  #list index out of range escape condition
                if abs(lists[index] - lists[index + 1]) == 1:
                    flag_valid = False
                    break;
        if flag_valid == True:
                valid_list.append(lists)
    return valid_list

print code()
```

Comment: thanks a lot.I got it now :3